# How to rewrite class method?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, tchromium, chromium-embedded

Here is ceflib.pas code
[CEFLIB.PAS](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/src/ceflib.pas#7216)

So in `TCefRenderProcessHandlerOwn` class, declared `OnBeforeNavigation` function.
As we can see, it returns False everytime and its bad, because if Link was opened by `MouseWheelClick` it will not open this link in New Tab, i want to fix it.
The question is: How to rewrite this function?
TNX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used this library, but it looks to me like you need to do the following:

1. Define a class that derives from `TCefRenderProcessHandlerOwn`.
2. Override the method you are interested in customising. In this case `OnBeforeNavigation`.
3. At initialization time, instantiate your class and assign that to the `CefRenderProcessHandler` global variable.

```
type 
  TMyRenderProcessHandler = class(TCefRenderProcessHandlerOwn)
  protected
    function OnBeforeNavigation(const browser: ICefBrowser; 
      const frame: ICefFrame; const request: ICefRequest; 
      navigationType: TCefNavigationType; isRedirect: Boolean): Boolean;
      override;
  end;

function TMyRenderProcessHandler.OnBeforeNavigation(const browser: ICefBrowser; 
  const frame: ICefFrame; const request: ICefRequest; 
  navigationType: TCefNavigationType; isRedirect: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  .... your code goes here
end;      

initialization
  CefRenderProcessHandler := TMyRenderProcessHandler.Create;
```

The project comes with demo programs that illustrate this technique. I suggest that you study those demos to learn more about this very powerful component.

Comment: Yup. That's the right way. However, what OP tries to do will lead to some ugly hack, because though he'll be able to detect that the navigation was invoked by a link click in that event (when `navigationType == NAVIGATION_LINK_CLICKED`), he won't be able to determine which mouse button caused it. It's just too late to determine which button was pressed in `OnBeforeNavigation` event. I know it's out of scope of this question, but in my view, there is no clean way to resolve what OP actually wants.

Comment: @TLama I don't really know about that, and I'm very happy to take your word for it. I tried to get Riley to ask the question in a different way, but he was dead set on asking it this way. Hence the naive answer.

Comment: Exactly, i determinated by what mouse button was called this event :) HookForm

Comment: Well, i determinated MiddleMouseClick, but as @TLama said, i can't use it in `OnBeforeNavigation` event...

Comment: Why ? Just remember which mouse button was clicked last time in your mouse hook and take this value to the `OnBeforeNavigation` event method. There you can check (in pseudo-code) something like `if (LastButton = mbMiddle) and (navigationType = NAVIGATION_LINK_CLICKED) then TheLinkWasClickedByMiddleButton;`.

Comment: I did like you just said, but it not works, just like `OnBeforeNavigation` ignoring this `LastButton`

Comment: You need to have that hook in a DLL library as far as I remember. Also, better use `WH_MOUSE` hook instead of `WH_JOURNALRECORD`. And finally, you were setting that *middle click flag* only to True, but never to False. Rather try to follow e.g. [`this article`](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/mousehook.htm) though it's not the best. And please note, that StackOverflow is not a forum or *please help me to write my code* service. It's Q&A site, where every single specific problem has a separate question.

Comment: @Riley You are now asking a different question. I answered the question that you asked. At your other question I suggested that you asked a different question, to ask us to suggest a solution to the problem. But you preferred to do it this way. And so it is.

Comment: If i trying to execute this code: `ShowMessage(form1.address_line.text);` in `OnBeforeNavigation`, it gives `Access Violation Error`, so in case of that, it can't see nothing :( So how i can check `IsMiddleMouseClicked` if `OnBeforeNavigation` can't see this variable?

Comment: Please note, that StackOverflow is not a forum. It's a Q&A site, where every single specific problem has a separate question, so ask this as a new question, please. And don't forget to include your real code marking the line where you're getting that access violation. Thanks!